# Using QFileSystemModel to display only one directory

Tags: qt, pyqt, qfilesystemmodel

Is it possible to use `QFileSystemModel` to list only one directory contents instead of all drives in my computer (in Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be a function of your view, not your model:

<del>http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setRootIndex</del>

**Update**:

No more Trolltech links,
the updated link is [QAbstractItemView Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setRootIndex)